# Hoare partition scheme return wrong index

Tags: php, algorithm, quicksort

I am trying to implement Hoare partition scheme from [a qsort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) for arrays which can contain duplicate items, but every time I modify my code to pass testcases, it breaks another one. Can't figure out my mistake.

```
function partition(array &$original, int $lo, int $hi): int
{
    if ($lo === $hi) {
        return $hi;
    }

    $pivot = $original[$lo];

    $i = $lo - 1;
    $j = $hi + 1;
    while (true) {
        do {
            $i++;
        } while ($original[$i] < $pivot);

        do {
            $j--;
        } while ($j > $lo && $original[$j] >= $pivot);

        if ($i >= $j) {
            return $j;
        }

        [$original[$i], $original[$j]] = [$original[$j], $original[$i]];
    }
}
```

[Here my testcases](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/794afe8c61b8153e928338506f260e7aa7f2cc4f), I've already tried to replace **do...while** loop with  **while (i < j)** loop and put inverted condition with break statement inside it, like

```
while ($i < $j) {
    $i++;

    if ($original[$i] >= $pivot) {
        break;
    }
}

while ($i < $j) {
    $j--;

    if ($original[$j] < $pivot) {
        break;
    }
}
```

but it break **the testcase #4** with **[4, 1, 7, 4, 2, 5]** items returning a wrong pivot index.

Comment: `returning a wrong pivot index` What are `$lo` and `$hi` in that call, (what are the array values in that range,) and what is returned as a partition index? Quote from the link you provided: `Note that…the pivot's final location is not necessarily at the index that was returned`.

Comment: $lo and $hi are indexies of the part of array that should be processed with the function **partition** call, i.e. **partition([1, 5, 2, 8], 0, 3)**. As for a returning value, it should return index of array for element, that "sit in the right position", so we can split array by 3 piecies - partition($lo, pivot - 1), pivot, partition(pivot + 1, $hi)

Comment: I was interested in the values of `$lo` and `$hi` in the call you suspect of returning a wrong index rather than their roles (which doesn't change between calls…).

Comment: `partition($lo, pivot - 1), pivot, partition(pivot + 1, $hi)` misconception for Hoare partition; see, e.g., the wikipedia article.

Comment: thank you! I didn't understand the meaning of the returning value